# 3D GUI Shader Problem

Tags: c++, shaders, directx, hlsl

So I want to create one of these in my directX11 project.

[image]

The little axis there that shows you the direction.

I have a nice 3d shader for my world geometry that I tweaked from Frank D. Luna (He writes books on directX.) and another for my 2D UI so I thought I'd look at those and see what I could conjure up since I didn't know all that much about shaders to begin with. But this is what I came up with.

```
float4x4 gWorldViewProj;

struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL    : POSITION;
    float3 NormalL : NORMAL;
    float2 Tex     : TEXCOORD;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH       : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex        : TEXCOORD;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout;

    // Transform to homogeneous clip space.
    vout.PosH = mul(float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);

    // There are no transformations for texture coordinates.
    vout.Tex = vin.Tex;

    return vout;
}
```

This code works if I pass in a quad and render a texture too it. Then for gWorldViewProj I give it just the world matrix of the UI. Renders fine.

But when I tried it with 3D objects (anything that wasn't a quad.) nothing would render. The only way I could get it to render is by passing in world * view * proj but then it rotates around the scene when you look around because of the view matrix.

So the obvious work around was to create a view matrix with no transformations and that worked.

I thought I could just give it a world matrix since that's what I did with the 2D UI. I also tried world * proj but no prevail. Why does this shader render quads without a view matrix but can't render other more complex sets of geometry without the view matrix. Here is how I generated the quad.

Comment: I don't exactly follow you... Please remove all of the code except the actual VS. Please, then, add the code you use to generate the quad.

Answer (score 1):

> Please also expand on this: "world matrix of the UI" and show how it's constructed.

If you do not explicitly supply a World, View, or Projection, Identity is used. This has the effect of multiplying everything by 1 (no change). Using a world matrix without a view matrix is the same as using a view matrix without a world matrix; (X*1)==(1*X)==(X). I might be misunderstanding, but I suspect your confusion is stemming from that.

If World, View, and Projection are all Identity, then world-space, view-space, projection-space, and screen-space all have the same origin and units. If any matrix is not Identity, coordinates from the previous coordinate system are being moved/scaled into the next. When all objects have been located in world-space by their individual world-matrices, the entire world is moved/rotated/scaled at once by the view matrix. If the view matrix happens to be Identity, the objects are, now, *already in* projection space.

This is *what* you are doing, but its not clear, to me, exactly *how* yet; will update as necessary.

**Keep in mind that:**

```
translating coordinates (away from (0,0)), Then rotating them (around (0,0))
```

is **not** the same as:

```
rotating coordinates (around (0,0)), Then translating them (away from (0,0))
```

> So the obvious work around was to create a view matrix with no transformations and that worked.

Your intuition is spot-on; it is very common to keep the rotation component of the view matrix separate.

**Another note about view matrices:**
The view matrix does not typically scale coordinates; it only moves or rotates them. That means that world-units and camera-units are usually the same; only the origin and orientation are changed. When the camera moves "left 5", the objects in view appear to move "right 5", instead. View-space's origin (0,0) is the "camera"; to "make the camera become (0,0)", the entire world (including the camera) is "un-moved" by the camera's 3D position. Similarly, the world is "un-rotated" by the camera's rotation. A view-matrix is an "un-world-matrix".

If you wanted to render a mesh representing *a* camera (not THE camera, obviously), you'd locate the mesh in world-space with a world matrix. That same world matrix (excluding scale), inverted, is the view matrix that you'd use to render from that camera's perspective.